# How to create variable numbers of nested "map" functions in Scala?

Tags: scala

Based on user-input, I need to create variable amounts of nested "map" functions in Scala.  How can I do this?  Is there a better way?

Example 1:

```
(xml \\ "view").map{view => println("case from user input #1")}
```

Example 2:

```
(xml \\ "view").map{view => val viewEvent = (view \\ "viewEvent");
  viewEvent.map{viewEvent => println("case from user input #2")}
}
```

I'm NOT looking for how to do a switch/case statement (or if/else boolean logic) based on the user input to output Example #1 or #2.

I AM looking for how to created variable amounts of nested map statements based on user-input.  For example, what if the user supplied yet another level of nesting for the XML and I needed an Example #3 with 3 nested map statements.

Comment: perhaps some sort of partially applied function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive function:

```
def op(xml: Node, selectors: List[String]): Unit = selectors match {
  case s :: ss => (xml \\ s).map(n => op(n, ss))
  case Nil => println(s"Hello from node $xml")
}
```

Call like this:

```
op(xml, List("View")) // Case 1
op(xml, List("View", "viewEvent")) // Case 2
```